# strcat() won't exit

Tags: c, strcat

I'm trying to implement a very basic server in C, one part of which is constructing HTTP headers. To do this I have written a class called header_builder, which basically constructs the headers for me. One of the most basic methods of this class is append_header_line, shown below:

```
void append_header_line( const char *line, char *hdr ) {
  printf("Adding header line\n");
  strcat( hdr, line );
  printf("Line added. Adding ending.\n");
  strcat( hdr, "\r\n" );  
  printf("Success\n");
}
```

All it's supposed to do is tack the "line" parameter onto the end of the "hdr" parameter, and then add "\r\n" to the end of it all. The problem is that the first strcat call never exits. When I run this code, all it does is say:

Adding header line

Which means that the following lines never execute, and I can't figure out why. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show the code that calls this too please?  Also, are you sure that `strcat` never exits rather than crashes?

Comment: Are you sure you have room in your destination buffer for the appended bytes

Comment: *Shudders* at the thought of servers relying on `strcat`. https://buildsecurityin.us-cert.gov/bsi-rules/home/g1/844-BSI.html

Answer (score 1):

`hdr` and/or `line` isn't properly zero terminated and therefore `strcat` runs until it goes out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Probably one (or both) of `hdr` and `line` is not a nul-terminated C string when the function is called.  In particular don't forget that before adding the first header you need to initialise `hdr` to an empty string with `hdr[0] = 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess one of the strings is missing its null terminator.

Answer (score 0):

strcat need a null caracter in the destination, it will proceed replacing the first caracter of the destination with the first caracter of the source. Check if the hdr is properly initialized.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/